# MSBuild error MSB4184, The expression 'expression' cannot be evaluated

Tags: gitlab, msbuild, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

After a server upgrade (and all of its software), I ended up with this error in my pipeline.

**This error affect all of my projects (more than 100) in the same way after the server upgrade. All of these projects have the same yml script**

The error comes from GitLab job log:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(143,5): error MSB4184: non è possibile valutare l'espressione "[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension("Production - Web Deploy.pubxml")". Caratteri non validi nel percorso. [C:\gitlab-runner\builds\NcXd8-56\0\yourbiz\bizbraco-master\BizBraco\BizBraco.csproj]
```

I've tried to run my command

```
msbuild /m /nr:false /clp:Verbosity:minimal /p:DeployOnBuild=true /P:PublishProfile=$env:DEPLOY_PROD_PROFILE /p:Configuration=Release /p:Password=$env:DEPLOY_PROD_PWD
```

directly on server, but the server does not give me errors, and it's the same server used as Runner on Gitlab.

I know that there are few details, but I don't have any other specification.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working `csproj`. The expression works for me.

Comment: Hi @svenhuebner, thank u for the reply. This is the only row that regards the PublishProfile of my csproj: `<None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\Production - Web Deploy.pubxml" />`